# local declaration of 'date format' hides instance variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Getting 7 warning messages for these three statements :

```
 // And grab those date components for the same date
    hijriComponents = [hijriCalendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit |
                                                 NSMonthCalendarUnit |
                                                 NSYearCalendarUnit)
                                       fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                         ];
```

---

```
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateee = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

---

```
self.gDayLabel.text   = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)[gregorianComponents day]];
self.gMonthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)[gregorianComponents month]];
self.gYearLabel.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)[gregorianComponents year]];
```

Comment: From the warning it is clear that you have a global instance of `dateFormat` and a local declaration with same name.

Comment: This file bro :)https://github.com/0xack13/CalendarStepper

Comment: Check that `XYZViewController.h` file. The dateFormat is declared there as a property. Then in the method also it has a local variable with same name. Either rename the local variable or use the global one.

Comment: Search on the error message. This has been covered many times before.

Comment: Thanks bro ^_* Midhun MP
you are Solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

Check that XYZViewController.h file. The dateFormat is declared there as a property. Then in the method also it has a local variable with same name. Either rename the local variable or use the global one. –  Midhun MP 6 mins ago